# Recyclerview right border of item is cutting after notify data change

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, tabs, adapter

I am trying to build custom tab functionality using recycle view. [image: like this image]

so there will be multiple items/categories which scroll horizontal.
If you click on any item, there text color and background changes as per active/non active item. so that's part is pragmatically done in adapter.

```
nonActiveDrawable = context?.getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner_black)
activeDrawable = context?.getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner_white)
```

used below code in `onBindViewHolder` function

```
if(position != mLastPosition){
   holder.categoryTab.background = nonActiveDrawable
   holder.txtview.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.nonActiveColor))
} else {
   holder.categoryTab.background =  activeDrawable
   hholder.txtview.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.activeColor))
}
```

when click on item, `mLastPosition` changes and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and then the borders of items reset based on active/nonactive items. but items shows like below image

[image]

My layout xml of items is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_white"
    android:id="@+id/categoryTab"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/txtview"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried below solution on `onBindViewHolder` after assign all the text and background, but still did not worked..

```
holder.txtview.measure(0, 0);       
layoutParams.width = holder.txtview.measuredWidth + context?.convertDPToPixel(10)
layoutParams.marginEnd = context?.convertDPToPixel(15)
holder.categoryTab.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

I want border's background with full item not the cutting one last item. But if i scroll this horizontal to end, borders will be good again. but not when you click on item and fire  `notifyDataSetChanged()` .

Adapter code is

```
class NewsCategoriesAdapter(
    horizontalList: List<AppSettings.Category>,
    context: Context,
    private val theme: AppSettings.Theme,
    private val repoClickCallback: ((AppSettings.Category) -> Unit)?
): androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsCategoriesAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    var horizontalList : List<AppSettings.Category> = Collections.emptyList()

internal var context: Context
private var activeDrawable:Drawable? = null
private var nonActiveDrawable:Drawable? = null
private var mLastPosition:Int = 0

init{
    this.horizontalList = horizontalList
    this.context = context
    nonActiveDrawable = context?.getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner_white)
    activeDrawable = context?.getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner_black) 

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return horizontalList.size
}

inner class MyViewHolder(view: View): androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    internal var txtview: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtview) as TextView
    internal var categoryTab: LinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.categoryTab) as LinearLayout
}
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.news_categories_slider, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    if(position != mLastPosition){
        holder.categoryTab.background = nonActiveDrawable
         holder.txtview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(theme.accentColor))
    } else {
        holder.categoryTab.background =  activeDrawable
        holder.txtview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(theme.accentTextColor))
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        holder.txtview.text = Html.fromHtml(horizontalList[position].name, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    } else {
        holder.txtview.text = Html.fromHtml(horizontalList[position].name)
    }

//        holder.txtview.measure(0, 0);       //must call measure!
//        Timber.d("measuredWidth text "+ horizontalList[position].name + "--"+holder.txtview.measuredWidth.toString())
//        layoutParams.width = holder.txtview.measuredWidth + context?.convertDPToPixel(10)
//
//        layoutParams.marginEnd = context?.convertDPToPixel(15)
//        holder.categoryTab.layoutParams = layoutParams
    holder.categoryTab.setOnClickListener {
        mLastPosition = position
        horizontalList[position].let {
            repoClickCallback?.invoke(it)
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
}
```

My Drawable file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <stroke android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:width="5px"/>

    <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Share the full code in your `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the drawable resources as well. Are these 9-patches or shape resources or what?

Comment: I updated my question with more info as you asked

Comment: same question do you fix?